# Which Stack Exchange site is fit for asking domains and hosting related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was wondering if there is a site by Stack Exchange, where one could ask hosting/domain related questions.

Comment: [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7):

If this is in a **professional** system administration capacity:

http://serverfault.com

If part of website development:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

If for servers/domains hosted at home:

http://superuser.com

If related to web products (like from Google or Amazon):

http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Do read the about/tour page and the help center articles regarding what is and is not on topic before posting on any of these.